# Error installing addons in GRASS 7.0.2: File is not a zip file?

Tags: grass-gis, add-in, extensions, add-ons

When I attempt to install an addon in GRASS Setting->Install Extension from Addons and select the addon i want from the list (r.stream.order) i get the following error: "ERROR: File is not a zip file: http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass70/addons/grass-7.0.2/r.stream.order.zip"

I get a similar error no matter what addon I attempt to install.

Is there a way to download the zip files and install locally? If so where should I download these?  When I follow the addon links and locate the the location of this addon online, it does not contain any zip files.  (https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass7/raster/r.stream.order/)

What are the correct steps in successfully installing an addon?

Comment: i have the same Problem with the addon "r.viewshed.cva".
My OS is Windows 7 and i use Grass Gis Version 7.0.4. Output:
ERROR: File is not a zip file: http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass70/x86_64/addons/grass-7.0.4/r.viewshed.cva.zip Hope someone can Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 7.0.2 is an older one. The current release is 7.0.4:

- https://grass.osgeo.org/news/56/15/GRASS-GIS-7-0-4-released/

If you are speaking about MS Windows, the older addons are still online but you would need to copy the files manually:

- https://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass70/x86/addons/

Installation trough `g.extension` is no longer supported for this version. Install the latest release or as @gene says, use Linux or Mac where the addons will be compiled exactly for your version.

Comment: Thanks. I've installed GRASS, QGIS and OSGeo4W and installed the latest OSGeo4W which came with GRASS 7.0.4 and I was then able to install the needed extensions.

Comment: It might be good to add a version check to g.extension and inform the user about the newer version...

Answer (score 2):

What is your OS, Windows, Linux, Mac OS X ? It is important because the addon needs to be compiled

From [g.extension](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/g.extension.html)

> On MS Windows systems, where compilation tools not readily available, g.extension downloads a compiled executable from the GRASS GIS project server. On all other operating systems where it is not difficult to install compilation tools, g.extension downloads the source code of the requested extension (addon) and compiles it locally. This applies for both C and Python modules as well as any other extensions. The reason is that more things such as manual page are compiled, not only the source code (which is really necessary to compile just in case of C).

With the Grass shell in Mac OS X or Linux

```
g.extension extension=r.stream.order svnurl=http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass7
Fetching <r.stream.order> from GRASS-Addons SVN repository (be patient)...
Compiling...
Installing...
Updating addons metadata file...
Installation of <r.stream.order> successfully finished
```