# Unable to install add-on in GRASS GIS 7

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0, add-ons

As i tried to install add-ons in GRASS GIS 7 using the command as:

Say,

```
g.extension extension=r.stream.order
```

The following error is displayed:

> ERROR: GRASS Addons (r.stream.order) not found. Reason: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Please edit and add which operating system you are using.

Comment: @markusN, I am using Windows 10 64bit operating system and GRASS GIS 7.0.5 RC2 (64bit).

Comment: Please try again, the winGRASS server was down due to network maintenance...

Comment: @markusN, Thanks a lot for your reply. Yes, Now i can install add-ons in GRASS GIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments above by @markusN, the problem was due to Network maintenance.

Best

John

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question here: [Error installing addons in GRASS 7.0.2: File is not a zip file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192999/error-installing-addons-in-grass-7-0-2-file-is-not-a-zip-file)

You need to install the latest version of GRASS

Comment: i am using GRASS GIS 7.0.5 RC2 (64bit) the latest version.